# For a linear operator $T\in L(X, Y)$, when $T(B(X))=B(Y)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I am new in functional analysis. I am facing a doubt about the following:

If $X$ is a finite dimensional Banach space and $Y$ is a normed linear space, then can we say that for a norm one bijective operator $T\in L(X, Y)$, $T(B(X))=B(Y)$? If not, then in what condition we can say that $T(B(X))=B(Y)$? What will happen when $X=Y$ (i.e, $T\in L(X, X)$)?

Here, $B(X)=\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq 1\}$.

I was thinking about the norm of $T^{-1}$. We know that $\|T^{-1}\|\ne \|T\|^{-1}$ in general but if the above is true then in those case we can conclude $\|T^{-1}\|= \|T\|^{-1}$. Now, I do not able to find out when $T(B(X))=B(Y)$ will hold. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by $X=Y$?. Usually you don't really talk about equality of Normed Spaces but you talk about isometric isomorphisms.  There is no reason for the range of any function to equal it's domain as "sets".

Comment: As a start, maybe consider operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ whose matrices (with respect to the standard basis) are diagonal (take the usual Euclidean norm).  When is such a $T$ norm one, bijective, what is $T^{-1}$, etc.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron sorry for this late reply. Here $X=Y$ means if we consider the space $L(X, X)$ instead of $L(X, Y)$.

Comment: @leslietownes sorry for this late reply. If you can explain in a little detail that will be very much helpful for me to understand. When we are in a finite dimensional Hilbert space then we can look the above fact clearly. But what about if it is not a Hilbert space? Please if you can explain in a detail that would be very much helpful. Thank you for your reply.